# Is it possible to line up PanelGrid with PageBlockTable or hard code a pageblocktable

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, html, css

So I have a data entry grid that is a pageBlockTable.  I'd like to put instructions below the grid.  What control can I use to make the grids line up?

This is the data entry section

```
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!apps}" var="APM_Apps" columnsWidth="20%,16%,16%,16%,16%,16%">
```

This PanelGrid is not lining up.  Is there a way to make the panel grid line up?  Or should I use a different control?  Or is there a way to hard code values into the PageBlockTable?

```
<style type="text/css">
        .col1 {width:20%; text-align:center;}    
        .col2 {width:16%; text-align:center;}    
        .col3 {width:16%; text-align:center;}    
        .col4 {width:16%; text-align:center;}    
        .col5 {width:16%; text-align:center;}    
        .col6 {width:16%; text-align:center;}    
    </style>
 <apex:panelGrid columns="6" id="theGrid" columnClasses="col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6" border="1" width="20%,16%,16%,16%,16%,16%">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing to make the UI's similar.  I made a controller extension with a method to "spoof" the grid.

**Std Controller/VF Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="APM__c" extensions="APM_OpenChart">
```

**Apex controller**

```
public class APM_OpenChart {

    public APM_OpenChart(ApexPages.StandardSetController stdController) {}    

    public List<APM__c> getSpoofGrid(){
         List<APM__c> results = database.query('SELECT Name , BV_Result__c ,TV_Result__c FROM APM__c Limit 1');
        return results;
    }
}
```

**Implementation in the grid**

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!spoofgrid}" var="token" columnsWidth="20%,16%,16%,16%,16%,16%">
                     <apex:column> <b>copied</b> </apex:column>
                     <apex:column> <b>copied</b> </apex:column>
```